# PYQT How to stop items opening in a new window

Tags: python, class, pyqt6

I am new to PYQT and this gotcha below causes me issues all the time, could someone please explain to me where i am going wrong.

The issue is the with the following code I would like to load the class QExampleLabel into the holder (qmainwindow) the issue is when I run this code i get a pop window with the qlabel in separate. I assumed adding a parent to the Qlabel would stop this behaviour but it didnt work or I am doing it completely wrong.

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *

# appears as new pop up window 
class QExampleLabel (QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QExampleLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.label = QLabel("Test label",self)

class holder(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(holder, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0,0,500,600)
        self.myQExampleLabel = QExampleLabel()
        self.myQExampleLabel.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    myQApplication = QApplication(sys.argv)
    holder = holder()
    holder.show()
    sys.exit(myQApplication.exec())
```

Comment: "I assumed adding a parent to the Qlabel would stop this behaviour": in your code you are *not* adding a parent, you only have an *argument* named like that, which defaults to `None`. You should add the parent in the constructor, which in your case would be `QExampleLabel(self)`, and that makes also irrelevant to call `show()` on the label, since it will be shown along with the parent. Be aware, though, that: 1. QMainWindow expects a *central widget* (see [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmainwindow.html)); 2. you should *always* use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: @musicamante thanks do you mean I would have to add this    def __init__(self, parent=holder):
        super(QExampleLabel, self).__init__(parent) this just throws an error for me

Comment: No, I mean exactly what I wrote: create `QExampleLabel(self)` with `self` in the parentheses. Note that the further `self.label` you create in `QExampleLabel` is completely pointless and *wrong*.

Comment: @musicamante thanks but could you please show me i cant get it work that way I am doing class QExampleLabel (QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QExampleLabel, self).__init__()
        self.label = QLabel("Test label",self)

Comment: 1. remove `self.label = QLabel("Test label",self)` from `QExampleLabel` and just add `self.setText("Test label")`; 2. change `self.myQExampleLabel = QExampleLabel()` to `self.myQExampleLabel = QExampleLabel(self)`; 3. as already said, you should **not** do that in a QMainWindow, because you **must** use a central widget, and you also should use layout managers.